# Publishing Data on Screen

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and did the exercise in this video and I get up about the 45 minute point and everything works fine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6esTdOLXh4 after that I can't ge the two blog posts to show up as it does in the video.

I had named the new model "posts" unlike in the video which called the model "Posts" so I adjusted my code so instead of creating a variable "posts" I made it blogpost in view.py. Below I show the code for the model, view and index. THe problem is I can see the layout but it doesn't populate the blog posts in the jinja code. If I add static text, the static text shows fine.

Model.py

```
   /*from django.db import models
   from datetime import datetime

   # Create your models here.

class posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"*/
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
#    return HttpResponse('Hello from Posts')

    blogpost = posts.objects.all()[:10]

    context = {
        'title': 'latest posts',
        'posts': blogpost
    }

    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

Index.html

```
{% extends 'posts/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="center-align red lighten-3">{{title}}</h1>
<ul class="collection">
    {% for blog in blogpost %}
        <li class="collection-item">{{blog.title}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

So like in the video it should result in show me blog post 1 and 2 on the home screen, but it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look that in the view, you're sending `posts` as params to template.

```
context = {
        'title': 'latest posts',
        'posts': blogpost
    }
```

On template you must change the `for` for:

```
{% for blog in posts %}
    <li class="collection-item">{{blog.title}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```